# ReactJS e rotas

Tags: javascript, react

O framework ReactJS vem com a ideia de web componentes.

Pois bem, ele não utiliza o MVC

mas e quanto a rotas? em um menu? como eu acessaria meus componentes corretamente?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dentro de uma estrutura MVC, o React.js seria o "V" da arquitetura. Em outras palavras, ele é **só e somente só** a visão.

Se você acessar [o site oficial](http://facebook.github.io/react/), existe um fragmento de explicação destinado à isso:

> **JUST THE UI**
>
> Lots of people use React as the V in MVC. Since React makes no assumptions about the rest of your technology stack, it's easy to try it out on a small feature in an existing project.

Tradução livre:

> **APENAS A UI**
>
> Muitas pessoas usam o React como o V do MVC. Desde que o React não tem responsabilidade pelo resto do seu ambiente de tecnologias, é fácil utilizá-lo em um pequeno mecanismo de um projeto existente.

Em outras palavras, qualquer tipo de lógica está fora da abrangência do React.

Mas e aí, como solucionar o seu problema? O React é perfeitamente integrável com uma plataforma/framework MVC, tal como [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/). Se quiser alguma referência, veja:

- [Using React.js as a Backbone view](http://www.thomasboyt.com/2013/12/17/using-reactjs-as-a-backbone-view.html), para Backbone.js;

## Update

Conversando com o @Rodrigo nos comentários abaixo, percebi que o tempo depreciou um pouco o link acima, que apenas *funciona*, mas é de longe a melhor referência — inclusive, se você notar, essa não foi a minha proposta bibliográfica, a ideia é:

> [...] Se você quiser alguma referência, veja: [...]

Entretanto, como a minha arquitetura é sempre baseada em Backbone, há um tempo criei uma postagem em meu blog que explica como injetar controladores para lidar com a camada de diálogo entre modelos e componentes *de maneira eficiente*. Caso seja de interesse, [eis o link](http://oderdenge.com/injetando-controllers-ao-backbone-e-uma-boa-razao-para-fazer-isso/).

Comment: Discordo da afirmação, não acho que o React é perfeitamente integrável com o Backbone.

Comment: Desculpa eu acabei clicando e não consigo editar, mas voltando..

Discordo da afirmação, não acho que o React é perfeitamente integrável com o Backbone.
O React e a view do backbone tem a as mesmas funções, não acho pratico renderizar um component React em uma view Backbone passando todos os eventos (click, keyup etc) como atributo, sem falar na confusão de contexto, e de estado (state) do componente.
Acho que no caso do React, vale a pena utilizar o Flux, o MVC convencional não funciona muito com bem o React.

Comment: @Rodrigo Demorei pra ler, mas finalmente o fiz. Quando você utiliza a camada de apresentação como o React, você desanexa a camada "View" do Backbone. Em outras palavras, um mecanismo substitui o outro — não são usados em paralelo —, o que faz ambos serem sim perfeitamente integráveis e não há qualquer conflito contextual como você disse.

Comment: Concordo que é possivel sim e é uma maneira de utilizar, mas utilizar um componente react dentro de uma view backbone me soa estranho, e pouco reativo quando se fala em Flux. Agora utilizar o Router do backbone para enviar uma action de flux para um componente A ou B ser renderizado é outra historia.

No exemplo do site ele usa o react como um elemento stateless para esses casos acho que o Polymer é mais aconselhado já que organiza melhor os estilos (css).

Comment: De novo, usar uma view Backbone para renderizar um componente React é _feio_ — eu não o faço. No meu caso, eu desanexo _completamente_ a camada de apresentação do Backbone e deixo só e somente só a do React. Mas... entendi o que você quis dizer: está relacionado com o link que eu referenciei na minha resposta. Partindo desse ponto de vista, sim! Você está certo! Entretanto, à altura da data da minha resposta, não tinha encontrado qualquer alternativa para melhor referenciação. Inclusive, para somar ao tópico, fiz uma edição.